# Cannot store a file when a user doesn't have an SD card

Tags: android, file, android-camera

I have an application that can take photos from the camera, but I have a problem with external storage when users have set internal storage as default.

When I check available space on the external storage, it returns 0 bytes free, but the internal storage has 10GB of free space. Here is my code.

```
                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(
                    MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
            double sdAvailSize = (double)stat.getAvailableBlocks()
                               * (double)stat.getBlockSize();

            if(!Utils.isExternalStorageWritable()) {
                Toast.makeText(AddActivity.this, R.string.external_storage_not_available, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if(sdAvailSize / 1024L >  10000) {
                Toast.makeText(AddActivity.this, R.string.not_enough_free_space, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {

                File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .getAbsolutePath() + APP_PATH_SD_CARD, "");

                if (!exportDir.exists()) {
                    exportDir.mkdirs();
                }

                imagePath = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + ".jpg";
                final File file = new File(exportDir, imagePath);

                try {
                    file.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                 // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
                if (! file.exists()){
                    Log.d("App", "failed to create directory");
                }

                System.out.println("Dir exists: " + exportDir.exists());
                System.out.println("File exists: " + file.exists());

                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        Uri.fromFile(file));
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
```

When I don't check available free space, and start the take photo activity, I can take a photo, but the "Ok" button will not work.

What is the best way to store image files when the user doesn't have an SD card?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I posted a code here i use for getting the storage directory: [Storing .txt files on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541450/storing-txt-files-on-android/20541849#20541849)

i used it for creating new files, and it works with and without the SD card.

Comment: I think here are two external storages. First on phone and second on SD card, but when I haven`t free space on phone, how I can store photos on sd card?

Comment: The code i posted, first tries to get the sd card, then if it fails it gets the phone storage.

Comment: I tried Your solution, but it not work for me. Btw i can`t use cache directory for files which i need later.

Comment: Can you post the log cat what happened? Why cant you use the cache directory for later file use? I used it it many apps. Besides you can chose a different directory if you want to?